# PyQt5/QSql: application not finding postgres table

Tags: python, postgresql, pyqt5

Learning PyQt5 with an application for my business. Database backend is postgres. There are two modules; one defines the QSqlDatabase and opens it, the other should present the contents of a small lookup table, activitytypes, in a QTableView. The log reveals that the database table cannot be found. I need to learn why and how to avoid this issue in the future.

The log file:

```
INFO:root:found database
DEBUG:root:Defining model/view
DEBUG:root:model error:  Unable to find table activitytypes
DEBUG:root:about to execute select query
DEBUG:root:End of Program
```

The activitytypes.py module:

```
import sys
import logging

# bug fix:
from pdb import Pdb; Pdb(skip=['importlib*']).set_trace()

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtSql as qts

from datasource import DBSetup

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='activitytypes.log')

#logging.debug('running DBSetup')
#dbs.db

        
class ATWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Model/View here.
        table_name = 'activitytypes'
        act_tbl = DBSetup()
        self.setWindowTitle(f'{act_tbl.db.databaseName()} - table_name}')
        logging.debug('Defining model/view')
        self.model = qts.QSqlTableModel()
        self.model.setTable(table_name)
        self.model.select()
        model_error = self.model.lastError()
        if model_error.isValid(): # i.e. there is an error
            logging.debug(f"model error: {model_error.text()}")
        else:
            logging.debug("no model error")

        # Query to collect data to display
        self.query = qts.QSqlQuery()
        breakpoint()
        logging.debug(f'about to execute select query')
        self.query.exec('select * from activitytypes')
        

        self.table = qtw.QTableView()
        breakpoint()
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        self.setMinimumSize(qtc.QSize(800, 600))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)

        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ATWindow()
    window.show()
    #sys.exit(app.exec())
    app.exec_()

logging.debug("End of Program")
```

The datasource.py module:

```
import sys
import logging

# bug fix:
from pdb import Pdb; Pdb(skip=['importlib*']).set_trace()

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtSql as qts

class DBSetup:
    """ Set up database connection """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.db = qts.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QPSQL')
        self.db.setDatabaseName('bustrac')
        logging.info('found database')
        #self.db.setHostName('salmo')
        #self.db.setUserName('rshepard')
        #self.db.setPassword('ploofduh')
        breakpoint()
        if not self.db.open():
            error = db.lastError().text()
            qtw.QMessageBox.critical(
                None, 'DB Connection Error',
                f'Could not open database file: {error}')
            sys.exit(1)

        # Check that all database tables exist
        required_tables = {'activities','activitytypes','industrytypes',
                           'locations','organizations','people','projects',
                           'statustypes'}
        tables = self.db.tables()
        missing_tables = required_tables - set(tables)
        if missing_tables:
            qtw.QMessageBox.critical(
                None, 'DB Integrity Error',
                f'Missing tables, please repair DB: {missing_tables}')
            sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: I see a TYPO, change `self.setWindowTitle(f'{act_tbl.db.databaseName()} - table_name}')` to `self.setWindowTitle(f'{act_tbl.db.databaseName()} - table_name')`. If I correct that error I will not reproduce what you indicate

Comment: Thanks for catching that typo. No one else, including me, saw it. However, not finding that database table is still the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I learned that Qt5 added support for PostgreSQL-12 in version 5.15.0 and the installed version was 5.12.3. The solution is to build qt5-5.15.2 on my slackware-14.2 host. I'm working now on this.